# Checking three UITextfields for data, then performing an action

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have a section of code in which I'd like to take three `NSString`s (which have come from 3 individual `UITextField`s) and append them together to create a date within a `UILabel`:

```
-(IBAction)numberEntered:(id)sender
{ 
    if (dayEntry != nil && monthEntry !=nil && yearEntry !=nil){
        NSString *day=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", dayEntry, monthEntry,       yearEntry];
        [dateOutput setText: day];
    }
}
```

Basically I want the `if` statement to check that all textfields have data entered before it runs the `[dateOutput setText: Day]` line of code.

At the moment it acts as soon as I enter a number into the first `UITextField` (i.e. dayEntry).

The action is called on each `UILabel` by "Editing Did End".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the text fields are blank, the `NSString` variables will contain an empty string value (not `nil`) which is a string of length zero.

You should check the `length`s of the strings instead.  (Even if the `NSString` variables happen to be `nil`, calling `length` on them will return 0 instead of crashing.)

So change the `if` condition to:

```
if ((dayEntry.length > 0) 
     && (monthEntry.length > 0) 
     && (yearEntry.length > 0))
```

If you also want to handle the case where the strings contain just whitespace (eg. if the user types a single space in the text field), then you'll first have to trim the whitespace and then check the `length`:

```
NSCharacterSet *ws = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

if (([dayEntry stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:ws].length > 0)
    && ([monthEntry stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:ws].length > 0)
    && ([yearEntry stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:ws].length > 0))
```

Comment: Awesome, Thats exactly the answer i was looking for.  Thanks!